# How can I close my Turtle display properly

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I am currently learning about the turtle module in Python.

However, I stumbled upon an issue. I want to note that I ran everything on Jupyter Notebook in Anaconda, on my Macbook air (M1 chip).

The issue is when I ran this code below, everything went fine, except for when I closed the window, it just froze, my mouse cursor just kept spinning around on end. I had to force quit. And after that, the Jupyter Notebook page on which I ran the codes died, popping up a window saying "The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically" I have repeated again and again, but the same issue still occurs every single time.

```
import turtle

turtle.forward(200)
turtle.setheading(90)
turtle.penup()
turtle.forward(40)
turtle.pendown()
turtle.forward(50)
turtle.penup()
turtle.forward(50)
turtle.forward(50)
turtle.pendown()
turtle.forward(60)
turtle.forward(100)
turtle.done()
```

Before adding `turtle.done()` at the end, the situation was even worse: the turtle window lagging, and my mouse cursor spinning even when I did not try to close the window.

This is so annoying that I am not able to close the window without having to force quit and kernel dying.

However, it is weird that I am able to close the window without any difficulty when I ran this code, which is more complex:

```
from turtle import *

color('red', 'yellow')
begin_fill()

while True:
    forward(200)
    left(170)
    if abs(pos()) < 1:
        break
end_fill()
done()
```

[The capture of my screen when I ran the first code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/14kjp.jpg)

Comment: Does `turtle.exitonclick()` improve the situation?

Comment: No, it did not, unfortunately. When I clicked a few more times, my mouse cursor got a bit lagged and kept spinning, then I had to force quit.